# What is the real difference between electric fields and magnetic fields of an electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

So, below is a picture of a 3d electromagnetic field from a dipole antenna.

[image: 3d electromagnetic field from a dipole antenna]

As we can see, the electric fields and magnetic fields are basically parts of the same thing. Now I'm curious, what is exactly the real difference between the electric fields and magnetic fields of an electromagnetic field? The electric fields are actually magnetic fields and vice versa if we look at the whole perspective, like for example the vertical part of my body can be interpreted as the "electric field" while the horizontal part of my body can be interpreted as the "magnetic field" but actually there is no difference between them as they are just parts of a single thing. Another example is the vertical part of a water wave can be interpreted as the electric field while the horizontal part of the same water wave can be interpreted as the magnetic field but in the end there is no difference between them as they are just parts of a single thing which is water. Electric fields being perpendicular to magnetic fields, in my opinion, is just am another viewpoint of someone who treat them as different objects seeing from different perspectives.

Comment: The magnetic field components are the purely spatial components of the gauge curvature of the four-potential. The electric field components are the remaining ones. Concretely, an electric field will change the trajectory of a particle over time, while a magnetic field will change its trajectory over space.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux "Concretely, an electric field will change the trajectory of a particle over time, while a magnetic field will change its trajectory over space." so both are basically moving. They are waving after all, right? Therefore, no real difference between them?

Comment: What I said works also for static electric and magnetic fields with respect to the charged particle. Also, I don't know what you mean by "moving": a field is a field, it fills the entire space-time and the propagation of waves in it is to be viewed as disturbances, not as a moving field.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I'm talking from the perspective of people who think of the charges like electrons and protons as ball-like objects or particles. From the viewpoint of people who viewed charges as disturbances in the field, there is nothing that moves from this place to that place. So, in conclusion, from the perspective of those who viewed the "particles" as field disturbances, the electric fields and magnetic fields are the same and interchangeable.

Comment: I already mentioned their difference, see the two first sentences of my first comment. Of course, since the Faraday tensor is, well, a tensor, its components mix up when doing a change of coordinate, like a Lorentz transformation for example. But this does not mean these two concepts are interchangeable or the same. I recommend you look at the Wikipedia entries [Faraday tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Relationship_with_the_classical_fields) and [Electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field).

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux you said "Concretely, an electric field will change the trajectory of a particle over time, while a magnetic field will change its trajectory over space." sorry I think there is some misunderstanding. You mean the electric field change the path of the particle over TIME, and the magnetic field change the path of the particle over SPACE. So, electric field determine how fast or slow a particle is and magnetic field determine the direction where the particle go?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux sorry but actually I specifically talking about electromagnetic field like light, gamma ray, radio wave, etc.

Comment: @Frobenius I'm sorry I don't understand the link at all because I don't have a background in mathematics.

Comment: Ok, don't worry. I  deleted my comment with the link.

Comment: That’s a terrible rendering. Look at the one on page 16 of [this PDF](https://www.brown.edu/research/labs/mittleman/sites/brown.edu.research.labs.mittleman/files/uploads/lecture24.pdf). The electric and magnetic fields don’t look even remotely similar.

Comment: *The electric fields are actually magnetic fields and vice versa … there is no difference between them.* That’s **false**. In mainstream physics they are **not** the same thing, and there **is** a difference between them.

Comment: @Ghoster the electric and magnetic fields look different if people treat them as different objects, but in reality they are just parts of something 3d called as electromagnetic surface.